# Error "print __copyright" en python

Tags: python

Al momento de querer descompilar un archivo .pyc con **unpyclib** me marca un error.

Instalo la librería de esta forma.

`pip install unpyclib`

Y ejecuto este comando para descompilar el .pyc

`python -m unpyclib.application -Dq ClBarras.pyc`

Y este es el error que me marca

[image: Error]

Y no sé si este inconveniente es por que en el archivo .pyc haya una linea que haga referencia que ese archivo tiene copyright o si es inconveniente del archivo .pyc

¿Alguien sabe que esta pasando?

Comment: Eso ocurre por la versión de python. En python 2 se utilizaba `print <algo>` pero en python3 se cambió a `print(<algo>)`.

Comment: Te recomiendo cambiar de librería, pues la última actualización que se hizo fue en 2009. Por lo tanto dudo que tenga soporte para python3. Eso o en vez de usar python 3 en tu proyecto uses python2 (lo cual no recomiendo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto sucede ya que el archivo que trataba de descompilar esta compilado en la versión de Python 3.9 y la librería **unpyclib** solo acepta versiones de python más antiguas.